# TDD - Test if one method calls another

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

If method A's single role is to call method B, should I write a test that verifies method B is called when I call method A? Or is this a waste?

EDIT: I am editing to add some context. Here is my class:

```
module PaidGigs
  class UserValue
    def initialize(user)
      @user = user
    end

    def default_bid(multiplier = 3.5)
      PaidGigs::UserValue.cpm_value(@user.instagram_follower_count, multiplier)
    end

    def bid_value_including_markup(user_bid, multiplier = 3)
      user_bid + PaidGigs::UserValue.cpm_value(@user.instagram_follower_count, multiplier, 0)
    end

    def self.cpm_value(base_count, multiplier, rounder = -1)
      ((base_count.to_f / 1000) * multiplier).round(rounder)
    end
  end
end
```

Should I write a test that verifies '#default_bid' calls '.cpm_value' with the proper arguments? Is this a waste of time, or is there value in this?

Comment: I would personally find such a test silly.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError - Why?

Comment: I personally find a function that just calls another function even more silly. What's the point?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt that's called *indirection* and a common thing in object-orientation. I'd recommend reading "Design Patterns" by Gamma et al. when you have some spare time.

Comment: I have the GoF just three steps away from me, and I even read its contents. However, applying patterns just for the sake of applying patterns is actually called an antipatten. This extends to even OOP (which is a bit larger than a pattern but otherwise omparable), because that is a tool that well-informed programmers choose to use, but sometimes choose not to use. Like OOP, patterns are not the goal, hence my question: Why does this function do nothing else but call another function? Answering this is important for understanding  the goals and choosing the right test strategy.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'm not talking about patterns. Applying patterns for their own sake is an anti-pattern, very true. But if you read the part *before* the actual patterns, you'll find some basic principles of object-orientation, like **Favor Composition over Inheritance**. And this, for example, is where indirection comes in very handy.

Comment: Well, its still an uninformed guess, as the details of what's going on are completely unknown. And, talking about principles, in the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Don't test that one method within a method calls another. This will lead to a more fragile test, and create a barrier (although a small one) to refactoring. Your test should not care about the internals that produce the result, only that it's correct.

The answer changes if the method is delegating to another class - then you absolutely need to test, in a unit test, that the delegation occurs corectly by mocking the delegate.

There's value in methods that call others within the class: the name of the methods communicates the purpose of the method (if it's named well) and that's good for the human readers of your class. Well-named methods (and everything else) is hugely powerful, and largely underutilized. The names of low-level methods within a class can create a mini-DSL (Domain Specific Language) within the class, helping the reader to quickly understand what a high-level method is doing without taking the time to dig into the details.

Comment: while I agree with the readability part, but: 
1) from the unit testing perspective: if the method that calls another has some conditionals that make it call another or not, then it's worth writing a test for it
2) from TDD perspective you should start from the test, so testing the top level would be necessary. But I have to mark that I still experiment with this approach

Comment: @kiedysktos number 1 missed the point. You never test if an internal method is called. You test the paths of the conditional. If you then refactor out one or more methods, the test doesn't change. Everything is still tested. Your test should never care how the job gets done internally, just that the job is done right. This is part of the reason you always start with the test.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is does it make sense to **explicitly** test everything your object does, or do you want to **implicitly** test it.

This is mostly a matter of opinion.

Personally, I see no value in writing that test, because eventually you should be writing a test that mocks out the return value of the method and verifying that function your testing actually mutates the mocked value in such a way. This way you *implicitly* test that you're calling the function - if you weren't using the method to get your end result, then the value would not align to your expected result.

Edit: A code example in something a bit more readable:

Calculator.cs

```
public class Calculator {
    private IAddingService _addingService;
    public Calculator(IAddingService addingService) {
        _addingService = addingService;
    }
    public AddNumbers(int valueOne, int valueTwo) {
        return _addingService(valueOne, valueTwo);
    }
}
```

CalculatorTests.cs

```
public class CalculatorTests {
    public void test_adding_numbers() {
        var addingService = new Mock<IAddingService>()
        addingService.Setup(service => service.Add(1,2)).Returns(2);
        var calculator = new Calculator(addingService.Object);

        var result = calculator.Add(1,2);

        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(2));
    }
}
```

In this example, I've implicitly tested that adding service is the way that we add things because there's no action that allows calculator to determine this on its own.

Comment: *if you weren't using the method to get your end result, then the value would not align to your expected result*: this statement is wrong. Your test doesn't check that the redirection occurs. `Add` could return the right result without calling the service. It could have its own implementation of the feature, for example. And if both implementations diverge at some point, `Add` could begin to be broken without notification from your tests (because you don't fully test it, of course; as long as it returns your 2 for the naive test, you assume it calls the service, the one that is fully tested).

Comment: I'll try to add a better example, this isn't really what I would term as production style code, it was more of an example to illustrate that concept of implicit testing. I could just as easily make it calulator.add(1,2) and have the service still return 2, then assert that the result is still two, and perform the test that way.

Answer (score -1):

I don't see why you wouldn't test it. It's easy to do and partially prevents further refactoring of this method to break something.

Comment: Refactoring provides a number of benefits, including readable code and code that's more likely to be reusable, so the ability to refactor is a desirable goal. Testing for a specific method call provides no benefit, and has the negative aspect of reducing the ability to refactor and improve the quality of your code. Refactoring won't break your code, because you have well-written tests to keep that from happening.

Comment: @Don Branson *Refactoring won't break your code, because you have well-written tests to keep that from happening*: I strongly agree, that's why I recommend to test this method ;) The way to test it is debatable, of course. Anyway, I've never said you shouldn't refactor (you should!).